# Total probability of a given answer of a given number of additions

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I'm doing C++, and I want to find out the simplest way to find the total probability of a given answer of a given number of additions.

For example, the given answer is 5, and the given number of additions is 4 (x+x+x+x). The total probability that I want to find is 4:

```
1) 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 5
2) 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 5
3) 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 5
4) 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5
```

Another example, the given answer is 6, and the given number of additions is 4 (x+x+x+x). The total probability is 10:

```
1) 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 = 6
2) 1 + 1 + 3 + 1 = 6
3) 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 6
4) 3 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 6
5) 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 6
6) 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 6
7) 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6
8) 2 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 6
9) 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 6
10) 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 = 6
```

I have absolutely no idea where to start

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: The problem is of purely combinatorial nature. Best to ask that on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: i think your first example is wrong already because `1+1+1+3=6`... and even if we go to `1+1+3=5`, what about combination `1+2+2=5`?

Comment: You can't have a probability greater than one. You appear to be looking for the number of permutations of four natural numbers which sum to a given value.

Comment: You should try starting with defining the problem properly. What kind of numbers can you add? Real, Natural? Then the problem does not make sense but it is important. Also tagging it properly would help immensely. There is no `c++` at all, this is more of an `algorithm`. Unless you ask to write code for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry guys, it's more of an algorithm question. I'm developing it in c++ though, and I didn't know about the concepts of combinatorics and binomial coefficient. I can't seem to find a relevant tag in math.stackexchange, and I figured it will be faster to get answers here.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start for you.

Have a look at this table

```
        1   2   3   4   5
      +------------------
1     | 1   0   0   0   0
2     | 1   1   0   0   0
3     | 1   2   1   0   0
4     | 1   3   3   1   0
5     | 1   4   6   4   1
```

The number of summands is increasing from left to right, the total increases in rows, so e.g. there are 3 ways to sum 3 integers (greater than 0) for a total of 4 (namely 1+1+2, 1+2+1, 2+1+1).

Comment: It's Pascal's Triangle again. I swear, I had a math tutor once who could prove EVERYTHING with this thing.

Comment: Indeed, pascals triangle is all over combinatorics.

Comment: But this was not a combinatorics lecture, but Calculus 1...

Comment: @arne Sure, pascals triangle or binomial coefficients show up in different aspects of mathematics. However mostly I'd say it originates from some sort of combinatorial aspect.

Answer (score 0):

With 4 additions and a result Y, if all numbers will be positive and nonzero and small enough (<100) you can easily at least bruteforce this... just cycle trough all numbers with 4x for cycles and if they sum up to Y increment number of permutations. Disadvantage is the complexity O(N^4) which will be very slow.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int y = 6;
    int perm = 0;

    for(int a = 1; a < y; a++)
    for(int b = 1; b < y; b++)
    for(int c = 1; c < y; c++)
    for(int d = 1; d < y; d++)
    {
        if((a+b+c+d)==y)
        {
            cout << a << " + " << b << " + " << c << " + " << d << " = " << y  << endl;
            perm++;
        }
    }
    cout << "number of permutations: " << perm << endl;
}
```

Comment: This approach can be improved upon quite easily (as for given `a`,`b`,`c` and `y`, either `d` does not exist or is unique). However it also demonstrates how mathematical optimization (i.e. seeing that it simply is the binomial coefficient) is superior to brute-force approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is not *probability* what you are trying to find, it's `number of comibnations`.

Looking at your examples, I assume that the **number of numbers** you are adding is fixed (i.e. 4), so **every number is greater or equal to 1**. We can do simple math here then - let's substract this number from both sides of the equation:

Original: 1) `1 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 5`
Result of substracting: 1) `0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1`

When the substraction is done, your problem is the [combination with repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.

The formulas you can find in the link I provided are quite simple. The problem can be solved using following code:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}

unsigned combinationsWithRepetition(int n, int k)
{
    return factorial(n + k - 1) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - 1));
}

unsigned yourProblem(unsigned numberOfNumbers, unsigned result)
{
    return combinationsWithRepetition(numberOfNumbers, result - numberOfNumbers);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << yourProblem(4, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << yourProblem(4, 6) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can check this code out in [online compiler](http://ideone.com/ULQjPX).

Note that this code covers only the problem solving and could be improved if you choose to use it (i.e. it is not protected against invalid values).

Comment: Side note: Using factorial should be avoided to calculate binomial coefficients as those quickly raise beyond the highest possible value of an `int` resulting in garbage values. (Take e.g. n! / (n - 1)! for n = 60.)

Comment: @stefan: Agreed. As I said, my code shows the way the problem could be solved, and should be improved if anyone chooses to use this solution.